# PLaying Video in Background in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, silverlight-3.0

I am developing an app for Wp7.x and Wp8 which runs YouTube Video with lock screen disabled.
I have seen that new version of MyTube App and Microsoft version of your tube app which has been pulled back had a feature which allows user to keep listening to Video(Audio part) when phone is locked via lock screen. I want to Develop a YouTube Radio type of app which keeps pulling new Specific type of Viedo Url from youTube site and play the audio part even if running in background or In a Locked screen.

See MyTube App in wp8 store to know more what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone application goes to dormant/tombstone mode when the phone screen is locked. This behavior can be altered by changing the properties UserIdleDetectionMode and ApplicationIdleDetectionMode of PhoneApplicationService class. By default UserIdleDetectionMode and ApplicationIdleDetectionMode are set to Enable, which allows the service to lock the phone when the user is idle and these deactivate the application when the phone is locked.

As shown below, I have used ApplicationIdleDetectionMode, which when set to Disable doesn't deactivate the application when the phone is locked.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
if (rootFrame != null)            
{                
     rootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(rootFrame_Obscured);                
     rootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(rootFrame_Unobscured);            
}
```

Once ApplicationIdleDetectionMode is Disabled, it cannot be Enabled until the application is re-launched. If you try to enable it, it will throw an exception. To handle the locking and unlocking state of the device you can call the Obscured and Unobscured event handler of RootFrame. Obscured will be called when the phone is getting locked. Here we should use minimum CPU, less battery consumption etc. and Unobscured gets called when the phone is getting unlocked. This is the stage when we can resume all the states of the application.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you send me example of how obscured and unobscured event should be used to meet my needs. Do I need to send the audio to background player for videos inorder to continue it to play in locked screen. If I am playing a radio,once video stops I need to move to second video/audio without user intervention.. how to do that when screen is locked?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8, you can actually give video URLs to the `BackgroundAudioPlayer` class and it will play them in the background. I use this technique in Podcaster to switch between audio and video, though it's a user interaction that triggers the switch.

**Updated**

In Windows Phone 7 this technique doesn't work. Furthermore, MediaElement will always pause video when the lock screen is shown (even if ApplicationIdleDetectionMode is disabled) and there's nothing you can do about it.

In short, you can work around it in WP8 but there's nothing you can do on WP7

Comment: PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = 
    IdleDetectionMode.Disabled; this logic works only for audio tracks which I play using mediaelement. what about Videos? Video gets paused when I lock the screen.

Comment: Actually I was able to solve the problem by catching MediaElement StateChanged event       . void MusicPlayer_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
                
                if (MusicPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
                {
                    if (rootFrameObscured)
                    {
                        MusicPlayer.Play();
                        rootFrameObscured = false;// toggle the switch 
                    }
                }

        }  RootFrameObsured flag I am settingwhen Root frame is obscured.

Comment: Now problem is Video frames get out of sync with Audio and when the music finishes playing, MediaEnded event is not called, so I am not able to switch to next video in my radio. Even if I send the music to backgroundAudioPlayer for WP8, how will I show the video when someone unlocks the screen?

Comment: By recording the current position of the BackgroundAudioPlayer, shutting down the background service (player.Close()) and restarting your video at the same position.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with little trick. I spun up a timer when obscured even happens to track timeLeft on Video playback and when it is less then 5 seconds I stop the video and jump to next one.It is not ideal, but seems to work.Unless you have a better solution via background audioplayer,i will go with this solution.

Comment: thanks, I saw your response. will try your solution as well.. thanks :) but my solution also seems to work, I just can't stop the video after complete end of video,i have to stop with atlest a second left on video, because timer can't run in milliseconds.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue but now after reading Application certification requirement, My app cannot rely on any timers when running under lock screen. If I will stop the timer, I can't go to next video while playing in radio mode. How to solve this issue? MediaElement MediaEnded event is not getting called when running under locked screen. please help

Comment: see my last comment.apart from what I tried earlier, I also tried BackgroundAudioPlayer and passed Mpeg4 stream I get after getting the YOuTube Url. AudioPlayer didn't ran the audio part of video using this approach. Am I missing something? The same stream works when I pass it to MediaElement. I tried compiling application in WP8 instead of Wp7.1, still same issue exists